# How F# inlining of ignore function works regarding side effect functions

Tags: f#

I was reading this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51640498/8634147) and I wonder how `ignore` function is inlined: its argument should be discarded but the side effect still happens:

```ml
// See https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/main/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs
let inline (|>) x f = f x
let inline ignore _ = ()

// Side effect function returning a value to ignore
let ok () =
    printfn "ok"
    true

// Usage
let t1 = ok () |> ignore
//     = ignore (ok ()) // `|>` inlined
//     = ()             // `ignore` inlined
//     what happened for `printfn "ok"` inside the `ok` function?
```

Console output:

```
ok
val ok : unit -> bool
val t1 : unit = ()
```

When executing the code in the FSI, the "ok" is printed when compiling (as it appeared before `val ok : unit -> bool`).

→ What will happen when executing the code inside a  `.fs` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the output from F# interactive is slightly confusing - it does not run the function while compiling. It first compiles the code, then runs it and then prints the resulting types and values of all results. It needs to run the code before printing, because it also prints the final values.

As for what is going on, let's look what happens if you have just:

```
let ok () = printfn "ok"; true
```

- We start with `let t1 = ok () |> ignore`
- After inlining of `|>`, this becomes `let t1 = ignore(ok())`
- After inlining of `ignore`, this becomes `let t1 = ok(); ()`
- Now you have an expression composed using `;` so F# evaluates the first sub-expression, which is the call to the `ok()` function. You get `let t1 = (printf "ok"; true); ()`
- The expressions are evaluated from left to right, so this runs the printing (performs the side effect) and the result of printf is a unit value `()`. So we now have `let t1 = ((); true); ()`.
- Now, the `;` operator is evaluated and `()` is discarded. We have `let t1 = true; ()`
- Now, the second `;` operator is evaluated and `true` is discarded. We have `let t1 = ()`. That's the final result!